# Posting links on Chatter - Open Graph support

Tags: chatter

it seems that Chatter will read Open Graph meta data from some sites but not others.

For example, Chatter will read the Open Graph tags from these sites:
youtube.com
bbc.co.uk/sport/live/football/33674052
facebook.com

Whereas these will not:
grey.co.uk/
ebay.co.uk
sony.com

But, other social networking sites will successfully read the open graph tags from all sites.

Does anybody know if chatter actually uses open graph, and if so are there any special restrictions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chatter uses embed.ly for the link previews, and only specific sites are supported. The current list is at this help page: [Sites That Generate a Preview in Posts](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_attach_file_reference.htm&language=en)

Comment: Thank you alouie, this is really helpful - now it makes sense!